# How to rename subcommand placeholder in clap_derive?

Tags: rust, clap

How can I rename the placeholder `<COMMAND>` of a subcommand when using `clap_derive`?

Here's an MRE:
`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "clap_test_subcommand_placeholder"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.4.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
use clap::{Parser, Subcommand};

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = "Frobnicate the fizzbuzz")]
struct Args {
    #[arg(index = 1, name = "xml_file", help = "The base XML file to operate on")]
    file: String,
    #[command(subcommand, name = "action")]
    action: Action,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Subcommand)]
pub enum Action {
    #[command(long_about = "Add a new type")]
    Add,
    #[command(long_about = "Display the selected type's properties")]
    Find,
}

fn main() {
    Args::parse();
}
```

The flag `name` is accepted by the compiler, but does not seem to have an effect:

```
〉cargo run                                                                                                                      2023-08-27 11:35:07
   Compiling clap_test_subcommand_placeholder v0.1.0 (/home/rne/clap_test_subcommand_placeholder)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.65s
     Running `target/debug/clap_test_subcommand_placeholder`
Usage: clap_test_subcommand_placeholder <xml_file> <COMMAND>

Commands:
  add   Add a new type
  find  Display the selected type's properties
  help  Print this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)

Arguments:
  <xml_file>  The base XML file to operate on

Options:
  -h, --help     Print help (see more with '--help')
  -V, --version  Print version
```

It still says `<COMMAND>` instead of `<action>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `subcommand_value_name = "action"` in the `#[command]`:

```rust
use clap::{Parser, Subcommand};

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
#[command(
    author,
    version,
    about,
    long_about = "Frobnicate the fizzbuzz",
    subcommand_value_name = "action"
)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(index = 1, name = "xml_file", help = "The base XML file to operate on")]
    file: String,
    #[command(subcommand, name = "action")]
    action: Action,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Subcommand)]
pub enum Action {
    #[command(long_about = "Add a new type")]
    Add,
    #[command(long_about = "Display the selected type's properties")]
    Find,
}

fn main() {
    Args::parse();
}
```

Output:

```
Usage: playground <xml_file> <action>

Commands:
  add   Add a new type
  find  Display the selected type's properties
  help  Print this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)

Arguments:
  <xml_file>  The base XML file to operate on

Options:
  -h, --help     Print help (see more with '--help')
  -V, --version  Print version
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72cbea10ffccaae00b7471f0cc35a48a)

---

You can change the `Commands:` in the help message to `Actions:` with `subcommand_help_heading`:

```rust
#[command(
    author,
    version,
    about,
    long_about = "Frobnicate the fizzbuzz",
    subcommand_help_heading = "Actions",
    subcommand_value_name = "action"
)]
```

Output:

```
Usage: playground <xml_file> <action>

Actions:
  add   Add a new type
  find  Display the selected type's properties
  help  Print this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)

Arguments:
  <xml_file>  The base XML file to operate on

Options:
  -h, --help     Print help (see more with '--help')
  -V, --version  Print version
```